# Extract certain lines from a Nginx version info

Tags: linux, shell, nginx

I need to extract the arguments from the Nginx version info I am getting the Nginx version info using the below command

```
nginx -V
```

I got the below output

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-GkiujU/nginx- 
1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time - 
D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' - 
-prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log- 
path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock- 
path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules -- 
http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp- 
path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp- 
path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with- 
pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module -- 
with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with- 
http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with- 
http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with- 
http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic -- 
with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

I need to extract the below text from above output

```
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-GkiujU/nginx- 
1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time - 
D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' - 
-prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log- 
path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock- 
path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules -- 
http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp- 
path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp- 
path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with- 
pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module -- 
with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with- 
http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with- 
http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with- 
http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic -- 
with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

I tried it using multiple approaches, but still can't find a way to do that

I have used the awk command like shown below

```
nginx -V | awk -F 'arguments:' '{print 2}'
```

Can someone please help me out here with this

Comment: I need to store it in a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use a file write to get the values from the output I need

```
nginx -V &> test
awk -F'arguments:' '{print $2}' test
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for similar problem

Answer (score 0):

These are my versions based on the examples above

```
$ nginx -V &> tmp && cat tmp | head -n 2 && rm tmp >> logFile
..or
$ echo $(nginx -V &> tmp && cat tmp | head -n 2 >> logFile) && rm tmp
$ cat logFile
```

Answer (score -1):

For reference, it may not be perfect

```
$ nginx -V 2>&1  | awk -F 'arguments:' '{print $NF}' | sed -n '$p'
```